# node_modules path programmatically

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am using protractor and I want to get programmatically the npm node_modules path from the global system.

For example my selenium jar is installed here:

```
C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar
```

and I wanted to get

```
C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/
```

or

```
C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/
```

I wrote this small script, which will look for my jar in the paths

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var paths = path.getModulePaths()

for (i=0;i<paths.length;i++) {
    file = path.join(paths[i],'webdriver-manager','selenium','selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar')
    if (fs.existsSync(file)) {
        var seleniumServerJar = file
        continue
    }   
}
```

here I supposed that this function is available

```
var paths = path.getModulePaths()
```

but it's not. I used to write an equivalent in Python, which is:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Comment: you can use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/node_modules-path

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are expecting to start a webdriver manager programatically. Try below code:

var pkgPath = require.resolve('protractor');

```
var protractorDir = path.resolve(path.join(path.dirname(pkgPath), '..', 'bin'));
var webdriverManagerPath = path.join(protractorDir, '/' + 'webdriver-manager'));
```